# How to add class name for each columns of highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

- An additional, individual class name for the data point's graphic representation of higharts column.

---

```
$('#cpm-graph-chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0,
        },
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Graph',
        data: [0, 2, 4, 6],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    }]
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d2hnse0g/

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: `$('#cpm-graph-chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            }
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                },
                series: {
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Graph',
                data: [0, 2, 4, 6],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
            }]
        });`

Comment: Please edit your question and ask question properly with the code

Comment: You can set `className`(https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.className) property for data points. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1cmp0s69/

Comment: Use https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.className

Answer (score 2):

You can add an additional, individual class name for each point by using `className` option:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
            y: 0,
            className: 'point-one'
        },
        {
            y: 2,
            className: 'point-two'
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1cmp0s69/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.className